# Adaptive card is not rendered on Teams mobile app

Tags: android, json, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We have an external bot configured to use MS Teams channel using message end point web hook. The following is the message posted to the  Ms Teams channel by the external bot. This response gets rendered as expected when MS Teams is accessed via web browser or MS Teams application on desktop computer. However,  the card is not rendered (seeing an empty line/block without any content)  when used with  Teams application on an android mobile phone. Would like to know what is going wrong here?Is this feature not supported on mobile? or are we missing something?

````
   "channelData":{ 
      "tenant":{ 
         "id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
   },
   "attachments":[ 
      { 
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
         "content":{ 
            "fallbackText":"Adaptive card version not supported",
            "type":"AdaptiveCards",
            "body":[ 
               { 
                  "text":"Here is an adaptive card with a link to a task module",
                  "type":"TextBlock"
               },
               { 
                  "type":"Image",
                  "url":"http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"
               }
            ],
            "version":"1.0",
            "actions":[ 
               { 
                  "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
                  "title":"Open Link",
                  "url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/xxxxx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.com%0A&height=large&width=large&title=Wikipedia-Embed"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "replyToId":"xxxxxx",
   "serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
   "recipient":{ 
      "name":"xxxx xxxx",
      "aadObjectId":"xxxxx",
      "id":"xx:xxxxxxxx"
   },
   "localTimestamp":"2020-02-14T15:21:41.1360000-08:00",
   "channelType":"msteams",
   "from":{ 
      "name":"xxxxxx",
      "id":"xx:xxxxx"
   },
   "type":"message",
   "conversation":{ 
      "conversationType":"personal",
      "tenantId":"xxxxxx",
      "id":"x:xxxxxx"
   }
}```
````

Comment: I'm sending your exact card to my web session and confirming on an Android tablet, and it's working fine. Maybe one of the Microsoft guys here has an idea...

Comment: @Jobinesh - Why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: Sorry @KyleDelaney that was by mistake :) You were right  on spotting the error in the payload, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the card's "type" is `"AdaptiveCard"` and not `"AdaptiveCards"`.

```
 { 
    "fallbackText":"Adaptive card version not supported",
    "type":"AdaptiveCard",
    "body":[ 
       { 
          "text":"Here is an adaptive card with a link to a task module",
          "type":"TextBlock"
       },
       { 
          "type":"Image",
          "url":"http://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"
       }
    ],
    "version":"1.0",
    "actions":[ 
       { 
          "type":"Action.OpenUrl",
          "title":"Open Link",
          "url":"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/xxxxx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.com%0A&height=large&width=large&title=Wikipedia-Embed"
       }
    ]
 }
```